Why doesn't b = a; f[a_] := b; f[2] return 2?
As the title asks, why does
b = a;
f[a_] := b;
f[2]

evaluate to a rather than 2?

For me this behaviour is so natural. Just not to be too theoretical, do you know any programming language where the answer would be 2?

What is strange here? f is defined to have the value of b and b is defined to have the value of a. The dummy variable "a_" is never used.  Therefore, f is always a.

@y I'd say it's a variant of the issue I discuss in Final Remark section :) . First of all, we can't assume that askers know about other language, we can't say e.g. "This is quite natural in C! Learn some C first! What? You learned C in school but still don't understand? Then you don't really know C, go back to school and retake the course! " Then, there doesn't seem to exist things like Set/SetDelayed/Evaluate/Unevaluate in traditional languages that don't naturally support symbolic calculation AFAIK, so it's not a very good idea to make an analogy between mma and C etc. in my view.

@DanielHuber OK, then why does b = a; f[a_] = b; f[2] evaluate to 2 :) ?

Is it really so complicated?

@DanielLichtblau Well, to convince the readers, I have to add enough examples. I think the main idea isn't that complicated? It's just "the a isn't explicitly there, remember this requirement is ubiquitous".

I wrote an answer to show what is going on.

To the downvoters, I am interested in what's wrong with my question, would you please elaborate. I'm not trying to complain here, I just want improve my question if possible.

To the close voters, since you guys vote to close this question with the reason "This question arises due to a simple mistake such as a trivial syntax error, incorrect capitalization, spelling mistake, or other typographical error and is unlikely to help any future visitors, or else it is easily found in the documentation.", could you please show me the document page you're refering to? (I think it's clear the "simple mistake" part doesn't apply to my question? )

I didn't vote one way or another but I sort of see why someone might regard this as a basic error. The a_ is after all scoped. I could see a claim that there is a bit of subtlety since there are different behaviors between use of SetDelayed vs. Set. Though it still does not strike me as being all that mysterious. Then again, I'm used to it.

The answer to the question "then why does b = a; f[a_] = b; f[2] evaluate to 2" is that while SetDelayed (:=) have attribute HoldAll, Set (=) only holds the first argument (HoldFirst). I.e., SetDelayed holds the rhs, while Set evaluates it when f is defined. I don't think that this is particularly unexpected behaviour once someone knows the difference between Set and SetDelayed.

@IstvánZachar OK, then why does the evaluation of RHS make a difference? How will you explain it :) ?

When f is defined, Set evaluates the rhs replacing b with a. Since a has no value, and is in every way identical to a on the lhs (same name, context), the function definition can bound the lhs pattern symbol a_ to rhs symbol a, which is absolutely expected. In case of SetDelayed, the bounding of lhs-rhs symbols happens not at definition time (of f) but at call-time (when f is called). At that time, the lhs is not a_ but 2 and, since a does not appear on the rhs, the story ends. Moreover, internally a_ is likely simplified to _ in case of SetDelayed.

@IstvánZachar 1. "since a does not appear on the rhs, the story ends" Then we again go to that question: Why can't the clever Mathematica see the a inside b? How will you summarize this behavior of :=, With, Module, etc. in a simple manner :) ? 2. "Moreover, internally a_ is likely simplified to _ in case of SetDelayed" Why do you think so?

There is no "simpler manner" than understanding the attribute HoldAll in SetDelayed: it holds the rhs, so at definition-time, a bounding of a_ and b (even if b has the value a) cannot be done. Since the definition of f[a_]:=b does not involve the bound variable a on the rhs, it can be omitted entirely from the lhs too.

@IstvánZachar "There is no 'simpler manner'..." No, there exists. It's "The a hidden in b isn't explicit so a_ cannot notice it."

Caution
The post is long.
If you just want to know how to fix the code, please search "fix the code in title in 10 ways" in the page.
If you want to read discussions about global/local variable, please search Final Remark in the page.

Short Answer
The a hidden in b isn't explicit so a_ cannot notice it.
If you can't understand this short answer, please go on reading.

Long Answer
I've waited for years but don't see a carnonical answer for this in this site, so decide to step up posting this as my 1000th undeleted answer :) .
The Chinese edition of this answer can be found here.
Before dealing with the question in title, let's consider another problem as a start:

Why doesn't the following sample work?
f[max_] := Plot[Sin[a x], {x, 0, max}]
Manipulate[f[max], {a, 1, 5}, {max, 10, 20}]


Reading this, those familiar with document of Manipulate would smile: "This is an example from Possible Issues section of document of Manipulate!" Yeah, and the answer is already documented there:
Manipulate only "notices" explicit visible parameters.
And we need to "redefine f to include the parameter a explicitly":
f[a_, max_] := Plot[Sin[a x], {x, 0, max}]
Manipulate[f[a, max], {a, 1, 5}, {max, 10, 20}]

"OK, so what? This is just kind of bizarreness of Manipulate!" Well, it's not bizare. Actually the explicit existence requirement (forgive me for coining a phrase) is almost ubiquitous in Mathematica. You may seldom notice this, because you can freely use Mathematica without knowing it in most cases (mainly because of automatic evaluation, which is also ubiquitous). But once you've dived deep enough into the core language, the requirement will be nonnegligible. Let's see another example:

Why doesn't
Clear[x,y]
y = x^2;
Module[{x = 5}, x + y]

evaluate to 30?

The sample is short, so Trace is handy enough for checking the evaluation process:
Module[{x = 5}, x + y] // Trace



Remark
Still, if you feel the output of Trace hard to read, consider the
tools in this
post.

"OK, so what?"… Let's replace Module with Block and compare the outputs:
Block[{x = 5}, x + y] // Trace


By comparing the outputs, we can see the difference: Module doesn't notice the x hidden in y. In other words, just like Manipulate, the localization of Module is also enslaved by the explicit existence requirement.
So does With:
With[{x = 5}, x + y] // Trace


And once the x inside y becomes explicit in some way, Module/With will be able to notice it, for example:
With[{x = 5}, x + y // Evaluate]
(* 30 *)

In this example, Evaluate has temporally penetrated the HoldAll attribute of With, so x + y has evaluated to x + x^2 before going into With. This fix doesn't make much sense though, because localization of Module/With will be broken:
x = aaa; With[{x = 5}, x + y // Evaluate]
(* aaa + aaa^2 *)

The followings are two better fixes to preserve the localization:
Hold@With[{x = 5}, x + y] /. OwnValues@y // ReleaseHold
Unevaluated@With[{x = 5}, x + y] /. OwnValues@y


Remark

With[{x = 5}, x + Evaluate@y] won't work, because Evaluate only has effect on the function next to it, see the document of
Evaluate for more info.

With[{y = y}, With[{x = 5}, x + y]] won't work, because the inner x will be renamed. This is also an interesting topic but not quite
related to this question so I won't talk about it here, you may start
from this post
to learn more.

If you want to learn more about Unevaluated, here is a good tutorial.



Now, we see how special the function Block is: even if the variable isn't explicitly there, the localization of Block will succeed. This feature is convenient (Names["*Plot"] functions are all localized with Block internally as far as I know) and dangerous (if you don't use it properly). Since we already have this post about Module, With and Block, I'd like not to talk too much about this topic in this post. Let's go on talking about explicit existence requirement.

Now let's deal with the question in title. To help readers understanding the topic better, I'll extend it to four related questions:

(1.1)
Why does
b = a;
f[a_] := b;
f[2]

evaluate to a rather than 2?
(1.2)
Why does
b = a;
f[a_] = b;
f[2]

evaluate to 2?
(1.3)
Why does
b = a;
f[a_] := Evaluate@b;
f[2]

evaluate to 2?
(1.4)
Why does
b = a;
f[a_] = Unevaluated@b;
f[2]

evaluate to a rather than 2?

"How to understand these? Trace doesn't seem to help much here. " Yeah it's not quite obvious in output of Trace, but we know that, the code f[a_] := b essentially stores something called downvalue in f, and we can use the function DownValues to display the downvalue as a Rule:
b = a; f[a_] := b; DownValues@f


And the effect of downvalue is the same as a usual Rule used in Replace, ReplaceAll, etc. In other words, ignoring the performance difference, code like f[2] can be replaced with Replace[…] in following manner:
f[x_] := x
f[3]
rule = DownValues@f
Clear[f]
Replace[f[3], rule]


f[x_] := x
f[3] + f[4]
rule = DownValues@f
Clear[f]
Replace[f[3], rule] + Replace[f[4], rule]



Remark
As to performance difference, you can clearly see it with
f[x_] := x
f[3] // RepeatedTiming
(* {2.26217*10^-7, 3} *)
rule = DownValues@f;
Clear[f]
Replace[f[3], rule] // RepeatedTiming
(* {5.72101*10^-7, 3} *)

Since it's not quite related to the topic discussed in this post, I'd
like not to talk about it here.

So now the question becomes:

Why doesn't
Clear[f, a]; b = a; Replace[f[3], {HoldPattern[f[a_]] :> b}]

evaluate to 3? How can we explain this behavior of pattern matching in a simple and clear way?

Reading all the stuff above, probably you know what I'll say: it's because pattern matching only matches expression explicitly there. Though a a is stored in b in HoldPattern[f[a_]] :> b, it's not explicit. In other words, the a_ in left hand side of :> cannot notice the a hidden in b, so the replacement fails.
OK, then why does b = a; f[a_] = b; f[2] return 2? This is where automatic evaluation comes into play. We know that, the function Set (=) owns attribute HoldFirst (unlike SetDelayed (:=), which owns the attribute HoldAll):
Attributes@Set
(* {HoldFirst, Protected, SequenceHold} *)

In other words, the second argument of Set i.e. right hand side of = will automatically evaluate before it's controlled by Set:
b = a; Trace[f[a_] = b]


This automatic evaluation has stripped the shell (in this case, b) outside of a. Let's check the downvalue in this case:
b = a; f[a_] = b;
f // DownValues
(* {HoldPattern[f[a_]] :> a} *)

As we can see, the a is explicit in right hand side of the :> in this case, so the pattern matching will happen as expected.
The example (1.3) can be explained in a similar manner: though we've used SetDelayed in b = a; f[a_] := Evaluate@b; f[2], the Evaluate has enforced evaluation of second argument so the HoldAll attribute doesn't have any effect on right hand side of := in this case, and the a inside b becomes explicit. This can be seen with Trace and DownValues:
b = a;
Trace[f[a_] := Evaluate@b]
DownValues@f



Remark
Notice that, just like the With[…, Evaluate@…]  example above, using
SetDelayed doesn't show any advantage compared with Set in this
case, because the localization is broken. (But still, SetDelayed has caused a tiny difference in this case, see this post for more info. )

On the contrary, though we've used Set in the example (1.4), the Unevaluated has stopped the automatic evaluation once, so, unlike the example (1.2), this time the shell isn't stripped, and the a inside b doesn't become explicit, so f[2] won't evaluate to 2:
b = a;
Trace[f[a_] = Unevaluated@b]
f // DownValues



Remark
These four examples show us that, when defining a function, one should
not blindly rely on Set (=) or SetDelayed (:=) only. To
choose between = and :=, you don't need any rule of thumb, just
think about the following:

Can the right hand side of =/:= be evaluated instantly?

Should the right hand side of =/:= be evaluated instantly?




For better illustration let's see another three examples:

(2.1)
Why doesn't
2 /. (1 -> a)

evaluate to 2 a?
(2.2)
Why does
1 + 1 /. (2 -> a)

evaluate to a?
(2.3)
Why doesn't
Unevaluated[1 + 1] /. (2 -> a)

evaluate to a?

Again, this can be explained by explicit existence requirement. Being intelligent creatures, we human beings can realize 2 in example (2.1) is equal to 1 + 1, but Mathematica isn't matching in this manner, it only checks if 1 explicitly, clearly, visably, literally exists in the left hand side of /.. 1 won't match 2, just as abc won't match defg.

Remark
If pattern matching is kind of semantic matching then it'll really be a
disaster: should 2 match 1 + 1 or 2 × 1 or 2 × 1 × 1…?

"OK, now I understand (2.1), then why does the matching succeed in (2.2)?" Because the automatic evaluation is there. ReplaceAll (/.) is a function without attribute like HoldAll, HoldFirst, etc:

In other words, the arguments of ReplaceAll will evaluate before going into ReplaceAll. Let's Trace:
1 + 1 /. (2 -> a) // Trace


As we can see, 1 + 1 has evaluated to 2, which matches the rule 2 -> a. But for
Unevaluated[1 + 1] /. (2 -> a)

the automatic evaluation of 1 + 1 in left hand side is stopped by Unevaluated, so ReplaceAll doesn't notice the 2 (in semantic sense), and the replacement doesn't happen.
Similarly,
Unevaluated[1 + 1] /. (1 + 1 -> a)

won't evaluate to a, and
Unevaluated[1 + 1] /. (HoldPattern[1 + 1] -> a)

will evaluate to a. The only thing that's worth noticing is, the HoldPattern cannot be replace by Unevaluated in this example, see this post for more info.

Remark
This isn't quite related to the topic discussed in this post, but do
you know what will be the output of the following?:
a/. b_. c_ :> c^2

If you feel confused, read
this.


As mentioned in the beginning of this post:

The explicit existence requirement is almost ubiquitous in Mathematica. You may seldom notice this, because you can freely use Mathematica without knowing it in most cases (mainly because of automatic evaluation, which is also ubiquitous).

To illustrate the ubiquitousnes of automatic evaluation, I'll add one more example. We know Thread is a useful function, it can be used in the following manner:
Clear[f, a, b, c]
lst = {a, b, c}; Thread[f[lst]]
(* {f[a], f[b], f[c]} *)

But,
lst = {a, b, c};
Thread[Unevaluated@f[lst]]
(* f[{a, b, c}] *)

Why?
Because Thread is also enslaved by the explicit existence requirement. Given that Thread doesn't have any Hold* attribute, its arguments always automatically evaluate unless we intentionally adjust evaluation order (as I've done with Unevaluated above), so we almost never have a chance to notice the influence of explicit existence requirement on Thread in our daily life.
Again, let's Trace:
lst = {a, b, c}; Thread[f[lst]] // Trace


As we can see, f[lst] already becomes f[{a, b, c}] before going into Thread, so Thread can notice the structure therein, but:
lst = {a, b, c}; Thread[Unevaluated@f[lst]] // Trace


In this example, what's going into Thread is just f[lst], the list {a, b, c} stored in lst is not explicit. In the eyes of Thread, the code is just the same as
Clear@lst; Thread[f[lst]]

So the transformation won't happen.

Time to end this post. Well, though I intended to talk about explicit existence requirement, discussions about evaluation order, pattern matching, etc. have involved in, but the various topics about core language are just related to each other, so it's a bit hard for me to discuss them separately. Explicit existence requirement isn't the only possible summary for the behavior discussed in this post, and there exist at least two alternatives:

In document Blocks Compared with Modules, behavior of Module etc. is described as lexical scoping.

In Leonid Shifrin's book Mathematica programming: an advanced introduction, the behavior of pattern matching is described as syntactic rather than semantic comparison of expressions.


These explanations are essentially equivalent to explicit existence requirement in my view. I prefer the explicit existence requirement because it's a straightforward explanation stems from the document of Manipulate. Finally, just for fun, let me fix the code in title in 10 ways:
(* 1 *)
Clear[f]
b = a;
f[a_] = b;
f[2]
(* 2 *)

(* 2 *)
Clear[f, b]
b[a_] := a;
f[a_] := b[a];
f[2]
(* 2 *)

(* 3 *)
Clear[f]
b = a;
(f[a_] := #) &@b;
f[2]
(* 2

(* 4 *)
Clear[f]
b = a;
SetDelayed @@ {f[a_], b};
f[2] *)
(* 2 *)


(* 5 *)
Clear[f]
b = a;
f[a_] := Evaluate@b;
f[2]
(* 2 *)


(* 6 *)
Clear[f]
b = a;
Unevaluated[f[a_] := b] /. OwnValues@b;
f[2]
(* 2 *)

(* 7 *)
Clear[f]
b = a;
Block[{SetDelayed}, f[a_] := b];
f[2]
(* 2 *)


(* 8 *)
Clear[f]
b = a;
Inactivate[f[a_] := b, SetDelayed] // Activate;
f[2]
(* 2 *)

(* 9 *)
Clear[f]
b = a;
Hold[f[a_] := b] /. Language`ExtendedDefinition[b][[1, -1, 1, -1]] // ReleaseHold;
f[2]
(* 2 *)

(* 10 *)
Clear[f]
b = a;
ClearAttributes[SetDelayed, HoldAll]
f[a_] := b;
SetAttributes[SetDelayed, HoldAll]
f[2]
(* 2 *)

Final Remark
More than once, I see someone trying to explain the topic using the concept global variables and local variables. This is not a good idea in my view, because it's replacing the original problem with a new problem that's almost equivalently complicated: how will you explain the meaning of global/local variable? To make these concepts really clear, your explanation will finally contain something similar to explicit existence requirement, this is called xzczd's tenth rule.

To the downvoter, I am interested in what's wrong with my answer, would you please elaborate. I'm not trying to complain here, I just want improve my answer if possible.

I think this is a good answer, but it doesn't touch on the fundamental concepts behind constructs like Module, With and Block: Module/With are lexical  scoping constructs while Block is a dynamic scoping construct. The documentation has a good discussion about this. Other scoping constructs like Function, Table Manipulate and SetDelayed all follow this logic in some way or another.

@SjoerdSmit I tried to avoid discussing too much about With, Module and Block, but indeed, I should have mentioned the phrase lexical scoping (which is another equivalent description of explicit existence requirement in my view) at least. Edited. Thx for pointing out!

I downvoted purely on the length of the answer to be honest. Way too long to be a useful answer to such a basic question.  But I would also down vote based on the content - you try to answer this question without talking about scoping and local/global variables then you are just avoiding the real answer.

@JasonB. …Please see the Final Remark section in the end, I talked about local/global variables there. See also my reply to yarchik. I've added some guidance to the question, hopefully it's a bit easier to follow now.

Please don't modify your answer for my sake - clearly I am in a minority on this one based on the upvotes.

@JasonB. Not only for your sake :) . The other 2 answerers (both are long term members and with high reputation) seem to fail to finish reading this answer, too. I should do something.

I thinks it is pretty obvious why the first code returns a and the second 2. You can see it by comparing Definition[f] in both cases.
Clear[a, b, f]

b = a;
f[a_] := b;
f[2]

Definition[f]

Clear[a, b, f]


a

f[a_] := b

Compared with:
Clear[a, b, f]

b = a;
f[a_] = b;
f[2]

Definition[f]

Clear[a, b, f]


2

f[a_] = a


I don't think this answers the question. Please see the comments under Danier Huber's answer.

I think you do not understand difference between local and global variables. a in b=a is global variable while a in f[a_] is local variable. So f[a_] = a returns local value of a, i.e. f[2]=2. But f[a_] := b returns global b which was previously set to value a which is a global variable and this global variable a has nothing to do with local variable a in f[a_].

This is exactly what I'm discussing in Final Remark section of my answer, see also my reply to yarchik.

To understand what is going on you need to look at "DownValues" to see what is actually stored:
b = a;
f[a_] := b;
DownValues[f]

{HoldPattern[f[a_]] :> b}

And;
b = a;
f[a_] = b;
DownValues[f]

HoldPattern[f[a_]] :> a}

In the first case, f[2] is evaluated to b and b is evaluated to a.
In the second case we have f[a_]-> a, there fore f[2] is evaluated to 2.

But in {HoldPattern[f[a_]] :> b}, isn't the a right there inside b? Why can't the clever Mathematica see it?

a_ is a dummy variable.

Then what's a "dummy variable"? How is it related to my question?

@xzczd It's the design philosophy of mma which enables more general capablilities of symbolic computation and broader expression power and provides more choices to explain your thoughts.

The answer to "Why can't the clever Mathematica see it?" is that the definition of f is defined by SetDelayed, which does not evaluate its arguments (neither the lhs nor the rhs ) before actually calling f with an argument (SetDelayed has HoldAll attribute), hence the symbolic definition of f can't see the global a.

@IstvánZachar So we again arrive at the issue about "global", please see the Final Remark section of my answer.

@xzczd I don't think that your Final Remark really provides a low-level, mechanistic explanation. It does not mention scoping, the difference of Set and SetDelayed, attributes and evaluation at all.

@IstvánZachar The Final Remark section is not for providing a low-level, mechanistic explanation, it's just for pointing out that the "global/local" explanation is not low-level enough. Attributes, evaluation, etc. are already covered in Long Answer section.
